# How to define a generic primary key field in base entity?

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, primary-key

I have created a `BaseEntity` class which will have all the common fields of the other entities like `created_date`, `created_by`, `updated_by` etc., I also kept primary key `id` in there. I am using `extends` and using the fields from base entity class. The main problem is `id` field is of type `Long` in some entities and type of `String` in some other entities, so how can I manage the `id` field?

Base Entity Class:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3779027956207925319L;

    protected Long id;
    private String createdBy;
    private Date createdDate;
    private String lastUpdatedBy;
    private Date lastUpdatedDate;
    private Boolean isActive;

    public abstract Long getId();
    public abstract void setId(Long id);

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format(
                "BaseEntity [createdBy=%s, createdDate=%s, lastUpdatedBy=%s, lastUpdatedDate=%s, isActive=%s]",
                createdBy, createdDate, lastUpdatedBy, lastUpdatedDate, isActive);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a generic base entity, where generic type defines the type of your `id` column;

```
@Getter
@Setter
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity<T> implements Serializable {

    protected T id;

    // fields, constructors, methods etc
}
```

When you have an entity where `id` is of type `Long`, extend with that type;

```
@Entity
public class TableWithLongId extends BaseEntity<Long> {

    // fields, constructors, methods etc
}
```

or when you need a `String` type `id`;

```
@Entity
public class TableWithStringId extends BaseEntity<String> {

    // fields, constructors, methods etc
}
```

Comment: If we move `Id` to BaseEntity, how do we customize Generation Strategy? For eg. for `Long` we could do this `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)`. For `String` we might use `@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")`

Answer (score 2):

Modify your getter and setter, use parsing in them so that they get long data and give String data, or vice versa accordingly.